# Converting array to texture representation

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I am trying to represent an array as a tex2D in cuda .... after hours of debugging , i noticed that 19 out of the one million elements is copied wrong to the texture , means as a binary array , i got 0 intstead of 1 .

```
void evolve_gpu( byte* h_in, byte* h_out)
{  

//int SIZE = N * N * N * N * sizeof( float );
cudaEvent_t start, stop;
size_t d_in_pitch;
size_t d_out_pitch;
int len = 1002;

checkCudaErrors( cudaEventCreate(&start) );
checkCudaErrors( cudaEventCreate(&stop) );

// Allocate the device input image array
unsigned char *d_in = NULL;
unsigned char *d_out = NULL;
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&d_in, &d_in_pitch, sizeof(unsigned char)*len, len));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&d_out, &d_out_pitch, sizeof(unsigned char)*len, len));

// Copy the host input image  to the device memory
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(d_in, d_in_pitch, h_in, sizeof(unsigned char)*len
    , sizeof(unsigned char)*len, len, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));




/**************************** TEXTURE CONFIGURATION ******************************/
cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypePitch2D;
resDesc.res.pitch2D.devPtr = d_in;
resDesc.res.pitch2D.pitchInBytes =  d_in_pitch;
resDesc.res.pitch2D.width = len;
resDesc.res.pitch2D.height = len;
resDesc.res.pitch2D.desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<unsigned char>();

cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(texDesc));
texDesc.readMode =  cudaReadModeElementType;
texDesc.normalizedCoords=false;
texDesc.addressMode[0]=cudaAddressModeBorder;
texDesc.addressMode[1]=cudaAddressModeBorder;

cudaTextureObject_t tex;
cudaCreateTextureObject(&tex, &resDesc, &texDesc, NULL);
/*********************************************************************************/

checkCudaErrors( cudaEventRecord(start, NULL) );

// Launch the CUDA Kernel
dim3 block = dim3(THREADS_X, THREADS_Y);
dim3 grid = dim3((len+block.x-1)/block.x,(len+block.y-1)/block.y);//25*50
evolve_kernel<<<grid, block>>>( tex, d_out );

//******** kernel<<< number of blocks, number of threads, dynamic memory per block, associated stream >>>  *******//

// Copy the device result to the host
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(h_out, d_out_pitch,
                             d_out, d_out_pitch,
                             sizeof(unsigned char)*len,  len,
                             cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));      
for(int i=0;i<1002*1002;i++){

    if(h_in[i] != h_out[i])
        printf("i = %d\n",i);


}
checkCudaErrors( cudaGetLastError() );

checkCudaErrors( cudaEventRecord(stop, NULL) );
checkCudaErrors( cudaEventSynchronize(stop) );

checkCudaErrors( cudaFree(d_in) );
checkCudaErrors( cudaFree(d_out) );

float msec = 0.f;
checkCudaErrors( cudaEventElapsedTime(&msec, start, stop) );

printf("Basic version took: %f ms\n", msec);

}
```

Comment: SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), for questions of this type ("why isn't this code working?") that you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  I suggest you provide a complete code, that someone else could copy, paste, compile, and run, without having to add anything or change anything, and see the issue.  Create the data set and do checking in the code to demonstrate the data problem you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem I can see in your code is your device->host copy:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(h_out, d_out_pitch,
                         d_out, d_out_pitch,
                         sizeof(unsigned char)*len,  len,
                         cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

Referring to the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g17f3a55e8c9aef5f90b67cdf22851375), the 2nd parameter for this `cudaMemcpy2D` call is the pitch of the *destination* allocation (i.e. the pitch of `h_out`, in this case).  But `h_out` is unlikely to refer to a pitched allocation, and even if it somehow were, the pitch is unlikely to be given by `d_out_pitch`.

Although you haven't shown a complete code, assuming that `h_out` and `h_in` are similar allocations, that 2nd parameter should be changed to the (un-pitched) width of the `h_out` array:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(h_out, len*sizeof(unsigned char),
                         d_out, d_out_pitch,
                         sizeof(unsigned char)*len,  len,
                         cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

I'm also curious how your kernel can operate correctly on `d_out` (a pitched allocation) when you are not passing the pitch of `d_out` to it:

```
evolve_kernel<<<grid, block>>>( tex, d_out );
```

I would have expected to see a call like this:

```
evolve_kernel<<<grid, block>>>( tex, d_out, d_out_pitch);
```

but you haven't shown your kernel code.

Here's a fully worked example that I created around the code you have shown, with the above issues fixed and a few other changes to build an example:

```
$ cat t648.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <helper_cuda.h>
#define THREADS_X 16
#define THREADS_Y 16

const int len = 1002;
typedef unsigned char byte;

__global__ void evolve_kernel(cudaTextureObject_t tex, unsigned char *d_out, size_t pitch ){
  int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  int idy = threadIdx.y+blockDim.y*blockIdx.y;
  if ((idx < len) && (idy < len))
    d_out[idy*pitch+idx] = tex2D<unsigned char>(tex, idx, idy);
}



void evolve_gpu( byte* h_in, byte* h_out)
{

//int SIZE = N * N * N * N * sizeof( float );
  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  size_t d_in_pitch;
  size_t d_out_pitch;

  checkCudaErrors( cudaEventCreate(&start) );
  checkCudaErrors( cudaEventCreate(&stop) );

// Allocate the device input image array
  unsigned char *d_in = NULL;
  unsigned char *d_out = NULL;
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&d_in, &d_in_pitch, sizeof(unsigned char)*len, len));
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocPitch(&d_out, &d_out_pitch, sizeof(unsigned char)*len, len));

// Copy the host input image  to the device memory
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(d_in, d_in_pitch, h_in, sizeof(unsigned char)*len
    , sizeof(unsigned char)*len, len, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));




/**************************** TEXTURE CONFIGURATION ******************************/
  cudaResourceDesc resDesc;
  memset(&resDesc, 0, sizeof(resDesc));
  resDesc.resType = cudaResourceTypePitch2D;
  resDesc.res.pitch2D.devPtr = d_in;
  resDesc.res.pitch2D.pitchInBytes =  d_in_pitch;
  resDesc.res.pitch2D.width = len;
  resDesc.res.pitch2D.height = len;
  resDesc.res.pitch2D.desc = cudaCreateChannelDesc<unsigned char>();

  cudaTextureDesc texDesc;
  memset(&texDesc, 0, sizeof(texDesc));
  texDesc.readMode =  cudaReadModeElementType;
  texDesc.normalizedCoords=false;
  texDesc.addressMode[0]=cudaAddressModeBorder;
  texDesc.addressMode[1]=cudaAddressModeBorder;

  cudaTextureObject_t tex;
  cudaCreateTextureObject(&tex, &resDesc, &texDesc, NULL);
/*********************************************************************************/

  checkCudaErrors( cudaEventRecord(start, NULL) );

// Launch the CUDA Kernel
  dim3 block = dim3(THREADS_X, THREADS_Y);
  dim3 grid = dim3((len+block.x-1)/block.x,(len+block.y-1)/block.y);//25*50
  evolve_kernel<<<grid, block>>>( tex, d_out, d_out_pitch );

//******** kernel<<< number of blocks, number of threads, dynamic memory per block, associated stream >>>  *******//

// Copy the device result to the host
  checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy2D(h_out, len*sizeof(unsigned char),
                             d_out, d_out_pitch,
                             sizeof(unsigned char)*len,  len,
                             cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
  for(int i=0;i<1002*1002;i++){

    if(h_in[i] != h_out[i])
        printf("i = %d\n",i);


  }
  checkCudaErrors( cudaGetLastError() );

  checkCudaErrors( cudaEventRecord(stop, NULL) );
  checkCudaErrors( cudaEventSynchronize(stop) );

  checkCudaErrors( cudaFree(d_in) );
  checkCudaErrors( cudaFree(d_out) );

  float msec = 0.f;
  checkCudaErrors( cudaEventElapsedTime(&msec, start, stop) );

  printf("Basic version took: %f ms\n", msec);

}

int main(){
  byte *h_data_in, *h_data_out;
  h_data_in  = (byte *)malloc(len*len*sizeof(byte));
  h_data_out = (byte *)malloc(len*len*sizeof(byte));
  for (int i = 0; i < len*len; i++){
    h_data_in[i]  = 3;
    h_data_out[i] = 0;}
  evolve_gpu(h_data_in, h_data_out);
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -arch=sm_35 -I/usr/local/cuda/samples/common/inc t648.cu -o t648
$ ./t648
Basic version took: 3.868576 ms
$
```

It seems to work correctly and pass the test you have created.